# Count variable and group by another one in R into specific table

Tags: r

I'm not native english speeker so please be patient with my english :))

I have a simple problem but couldn't find any solution for it.

Imagine a table Year like this one:

```
#Day #Month  #Type of a day
 1     1      monday
 2     1      thuesday
 3     1      wednesday
 ...   ...    ...
 25    1      monday    
 ...   ...    ...
 1     2      monday
 ...   ...    ...
```

I need another column named D into this table Year, where should be counts of monday's, thuesday's etc. grouped by month. But the structer of the table must be the same. Something like this:

```
#Day #Month  #Type of day  #D
 1     1      monday         4  #(there is 4 monday's in this month)
 2     1      thuesday       5  #(there is 5 thuesday's in this month)
 3     1      wednesday      4
 ...   ...    ...            ...
 25    1      monday         4
 ...   ...    ...            ...
 1     2      monday         5
 ...   ...    ...            ...
```

For example: take monday's, so in every row, where is monday and where is for example January (month = 1), should be in column D number of monday's in January. The same for thuesdays, ... and for every months.

The problem is I don't want to use data.frame, because I need it into this specific table Year with all the values in it without any changes. The whole table looks like this: [Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkNUy.png). It's in a Czech language so 'Den' = Day, 'Mesic' = Month, 'Typ' = Type of a day. The other variables shouldn't be important for you, so I won't explain them there.

Could you help me please? :-)

Comment: You mean like this: `dates <- as.POSIXlt(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), 1)); df <- data.frame(month = dates$mon+1, day = dates$mday, weekday = dates$wday); df$D <- with(df, ave(weekday, list(month, weekday), FUN = length))`?

Comment: Exactly! :-) You are perfect. I knew it's something easy. Thank you very much!